# BizTalk Group Configuration

Tags: biztalk

I'm configuring a BizTalk runtime server against a SQL Server 2008 cluster. I used the cluster name in the configuration dialog and the SSODB was created successfully, but the Group configuration failed. Looking at SSMS, I can see that during configuraton the management and tracking database are being created, but the message box fails and everyhing is rolled back. Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the configuration fails, you'll typically see a log file at end of the configuration. There will be more information in the log file.

When you are trying to reconfigure, make sure you delete the SSO database created by the configuration wizard else you'll see exceptions related to that as well.

Comment: Thanks Sara, that worked - I have deleted the SSODB, unconfigured Enterprise SSO and restarted the configuration from scratch...